# Passing environment variables to autoconf's `./configure`

Tags: environment-variables, autotools, configure, autoconf

What are the differences between `FOO=bar ./configure` and `./configure FOO=bar`, where `./configure` is a script generate by autoconf from a `configure.am`?  I know that the former sets the environment variable `FOO` to `bar` before running the script `./configure`, and the latter passes the string `FOO=bar` to `./configure`.  I think that `./configure` interprets this (and remembers it?) as setting the variable `FOO` equal to `bar`, but beyond that, I don't know.  In particular, are there any advantages to doing it one way or the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Passing the assignment to `configure` as an argument ensures that the assignment is available in `config.status`, so it will be set on `config.status --recheck`.  That is the primary advantage of making the assignment as an argument.  Note that the current autoconf documentation recommends this over passing the assignment via the environment.  Older versions of autoconf did not allow assignments to be made as arguments to configure, so it is necessary to use the older form when running old configure scripts, and habits die hard so many people continue to use the environment.  However, it is a good habit to pass assignments via arguments.

Comment: See also the definition of _precious variables_ in the documentation for `AC_ARG_VAR`.  That's the way `configure` keeps track of which environment variable should be preserved for `--recheck`, or whose change should invalidate any configure cache used.